# Open clueTip from another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cluetip

I am using clueTip over `<li>` elements positioned on top of a picture to explain what is going on in the picture.
I am adding a key at the bottom that lists all of the points in the picture and I would like to make it that the clueTip opens when you click on the item in the key (in addition to having it open when you hover over the point in the image).

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up making some major modifications to the jQuery plugin. Then we could initialize the plugin on any element with a `data-in` attribute and have it open the appropriate `div`.

You can see our working example at http://2011.solarteam.org/sponsors/gift-recognition/view-of-living-room